# DotNetOpenAuth + MVC2 + Google App Standard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth, google-apps

I'm trying to authenticate users to my ASP.Net MVC2 app throw a google apps standard edition account. I could not found examples nor documentation to achieving. I looked into DotNetOpenAuth Samples Solution, but did not found an example according my needs. All the examples were working against google accounts, but no with google apps.

I'm a little confused. For example:

1. Do I have to place an xrds document on my site, or I can rely on google account's one (like "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/.well-known/host-meta?hd=example.com"?)
2. What about the certificate. Do I have to place it in my site?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/loginGoogleApps.aspx sample?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew's example works perfectly and it is using a Discovery Service providing a `UseGoogleHostedHostMeta = true` to the `OpenIdRelyingParty` class.

```
HostMetaDiscoveryService GoogleAppsDiscovery = new HostMetaDiscoveryService { UseGoogleHostedHostMeta = true };
...
relyingParty = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
relyingParty.DiscoveryServices.Insert(0, GoogleAppsDiscovery);
```

I didn't find a similar behavior in MVC.

Comment: Did you translate the webforms sample to MVC? Mind posting the code? Thanks.